# Django: Testing Formview can't submit form

Tags: django

I'm just doing a quick test of a CBV Formview. However for some reason the form won't submit and I've gone blind from looking at it to find out why. There is no error shown, when I click on submit nothing happens and it doesn't redirect to the success url or print out the test message.

Form:

```
class EmailTestForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
```

View:

```
class EmailTestFormView(FormView):
    form_class = EmailTestForm
    template_name = "site/test_email.html"
    success_url = "/signup"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('form is good')
```

Template:

```
{% extends "site/signup.html" %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block inner %}

<form action="" method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
{% crispy form %}
    <input  id="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-cta-primary" type="submit"/>

</form>

{% endblock inner %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup_view, name="signup"),

    url(r'^emailtest/$', views.EmailTestFormView.as_view(), name="email_test"),
]
```

Comment: Please show your url patterns. You could try overriding `def form_invalid(self, form):` and printing `form.errors` to see if you are submitting invalid data.

Comment: Does the page even refresh/reload? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: The page doesn't refresh or reload- no error in the console.

Comment: updated with urls.py

Comment: the page isn't reloading at all so don't think overriding `def form_invalid(self, form):` will do anything. Beginning to think the issue is with the template somehow. - Actually I think it's a crispy form issue - it might add form tags automatically

Comment: Look in your browser's developer tools or the runserver console to see if a request is actually being made. Check the console for errors as well.

Comment: No no request being made (thanks for that tip)  . Yes it's a crispy forms issue.  ( it automatically adds <form> tags - but doesn't seem to automatically add a submit button.) so that was the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: You can get crispy forms to add a submit button by customising the [form helper](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/d-0/layouts.html#layouts). Or, if you want to include the `<form>` tag and submit button yourself, use the filter instead of the tag: `{{ form|crispy }}`.

Answer (score 0):

this is caused by using cripsy forms to render the form, which automatically inserts a `<form>` tag when rendering the form.
From cripsy form docs:

```
form_tag = True
It specifies if <form></form> tags should be rendered when using a Layout. If set to False it renders the form without the <form></form> tags. Defaults to True.
```